# QGIS: Set CRS for vector tile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector-tiles

All vector tile sources that are supplied in EPSG:3857 WGS/84 are projected fitting to other layers, even when converted to other CRS using on the fly projection.

There is a vector tile source that is supplied in EPSG:28992, "https://api.pdok.nl/lv/bgt/ogc/v0_1/tiles/NetherlandsRDNewQuad/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",
when loaded into QGIS, the layer does match other projections and maps in the Netherlands, even when setting layer CRS to EPSG:28992

Since the data source is a server, I cannot change the projection by converting the layer, is there any way to load the data with a fitting projection?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what your problem is.

Comment: Hey Erik. 
When loading the aforementioned layer, it loads as EPSG:3857, with this projection, or layer set to EPSG:28992, it does not project fitted to other layers.
I suspect it's because they layer is supplied as EPSG:28992, but QGIS loads them as 3857? Is there any way to fix this? Example of mismatch: https://i.imgur.com/E8pISh1.png

Comment: Have you talked to the data provider about the mismatch?

Comment: Data provider cannot reproject to WGS84 and does not know if it's possible to convert/fit projection from EPSG:28992 on QGIS client side.